# How to configure nginx server to forward request to a node server with empty path?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-location, proxypass

i have an Nginx server with the following configuration:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.ca www.example.ca;
    location / {

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

and on the node server am listening to port 3000 using node express as follow;

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  console.log(' request received ', req.headers.host);
});
```

and i have a domain www.example.com which is pointing to the Nginx server IP, the test am doing is:

> http://www.example.com/test  result ===> request received
>   www.example.com
>
> http://www.example.com/test/abc result ===> request received
>   www.example.com
>
> http://www.example.com result ===> ( i get no result !! its like the
>   app.get did not triggered )

so can any one help me in this issue ? when i browse the domain without any path parameter am not getting any result, so its like the Nginx didn't forward this request to the node server !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you browse `abc.com` using browser or curl it will always send the path as `/`. There is no way to send a blank path

Next your nginx config is of a socket.io implementation. It should be below

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.ca www.example.ca;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Next you are not ending your requests they will be just timing out. Change your code to below

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  console.log(' request received ', req.headers.host);
  res.status(200).send("all ok");
});
```

Also when you have issues you can test it using curl like below

```
curl -v http://www.example.com
```

Comment: i already try this, still get nothing when using browser or curl !!

Comment: so do u mean if i use location / this will redirect www.example.com to the node server too ? the request in my case only redirected if i have something in the path, like ww.example.com/about !!

Comment: i found what prevent this request, its seem that when i use app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); to server static files from the public folder, then this request will not trigger !! i tried to remove the app.use and it works but i need to serve static files too !!?